# How to use react-router and Django templates

Tags: django, react-router-v4

Folks, 
I am pretty sure I am not the first one to stumble on this problem. But somehow I am unable to find any relevant resources out there.

Here is my issue, I have a backend in Django and my front completely written in Reactjs- React Router - Redux (nice combo right).

- when entering the url  webhost.com/, django provides me with a page with links to a bundle that is my whole react application and different stylesheets

The problem arise when I want to refresh a page, the browser still tries to query the server even though a route exists in my react-router configuration.

- I had a look at the answer here  (catch-all option) [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) , but I don't quite understand it and I am afraid to have a new redux state everytime Django will provide the user with a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup up a wildcard url pattern that will render the same view that gets rendered when a request is sent to webhost.com. I don't know if that's going to retain your store though.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think it will preserve the store

Comment: I think there are separate issues then. One is preserving the store when you refresh the page. The second being directed to the react app when you the URL changes and you refresh the page.